# Delay jQuery Ajax in For loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, settimeout, delay

I have problem to make delays between ajax requests in loop.
I want script to wait 7 seconds to do next one. Requests are not identical, and I don't know how many of them can be.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var announce = $("#announce").data('id');
    var lots_cnt = parseInt($("#announce").data('lotscnt'));
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.ceil(lots_cnt/20); i++) {
        $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: "/project/lots/"+announce+"/"+(i+1),
                async: false,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#console").append("<strong>Parsing lots from page "+(i+1)+"...</strong><br/>");
                },
                complete:function(){

                },
                success: function (m) {
                    $("#console").append(m);
                    addprogressstep();
                    setTimeout(function() { $("#console").append("Waiting 7 sec ...<br/>"); }, 7000);
                },
                error:function(jqXHR,  textStatus,  errorThrown){

                }
            });
    };

});
```

Comment: [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ro/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout). That said, sending that many AJAX requests isn't a great idea if it can be avoided. I'd suggest looking in to sending all data in a single request, if possible. However, you should ***definitely*** remove `async: false` as it's horrendous practice - if you check the console you'll even see the browser telling you not to use it.

Comment: Its not that many requests as it looks like, its between 1 to 6, so I think browsers and network are good with that. Unfortunately, I can't make one request instead of this loop, and I need this delay to avoid  "429 Too Many Requests" error.

Comment: Browsers are fine with it, however your server/hosting company may not be if you have a N users * N requests per minute being sent to the server.

Comment: @ГлебГарипов if you need help implementing my answer, let me know

Comment: @TKoL Thank you for your offer of help, it's highly appreciated. You gave me an idea how to solve my problem. I'll describe my solution below your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fantastic question!

I see you're using jQuery .ajax. According to [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/), `$.get()` now returns a promise. We can use promises to acheive what you want.

Firstly, in your for loop, `for (var i = 0; i < Math.ceil(lots_cnt/20); i++) {`, the first thing you do is run `$.ajax`. Instead of that, what we're going to do is *build an array of functions*, where each function returns a promise.

```
var funcArray = [];
// EDIT changed var i to let i
for (let i = 0; i < Math.ceil(lots_cnt/20); i++) {
    var getFunction = function(){
        var getPromise = $.get(...);
        return getPromise;
    }
    funcArray.push(getFunction);
}
```

Then, you're going to write a recursive(ish) function to process each function, when the previous one finishes (and after a timeout if you like)

```
function runNext(){
    if (funcArray.length > 0) {
        var nextFunction = funcArray.shift();
        nextFunction() // this is our $.get promise
            .then(function(resultOfGet){
                // do something with your result
                setTimeout(runNext,1000*7);
            })
    }
}

runNext();
```

--- edit ---
Here's how you might turn `$.ajax` into a promise:

```
function ajx(i) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "/project/lots/"+announce+"/"+(i+1),
            async: false,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#console").append("<strong>Parsing lots from page "+(i+1)+"...</strong><br/>");
            },
            complete:function(){

            },
            success: function (m) {
                $("#console").append(m);
                addprogressstep();
                resolve(m);
            },
            error:function(jqXHR,  textStatus,  errorThrown){
                reject(jqXHR,  textStatus,  errorThrown);
            }
        });
    })    
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't thought about recursion.  Your code didn't worked for me, it was trying to execute function from funcArray with i=6 all the time. So I did it that way: 
`var lots_cnt = parseInt($("#announce").data('lotscnt'));
 var pages = Math.ceil(lots_cnt/20);
 var currentPage=1;
 function runNext(){
  $.get("/goszakup/lots/"+announce+"/"+currentPage,function(m){
   $("#console").append(m);
   addprogressstep();
   currentPage++;
   if(currentPage<=pages) setTimeout(runNext,1000*7);
  });
 }
 runNext();`

Comment: Ah yes, when you loop that way with clojures the variable 'i' would end up always with the biggest value. I didn't think about that.

Comment: @ГлебГарипов that bug on the 'i' loop could be fixed by `let` instead of `var` i think.

Answer (score 0):

you can fix with `map` instead of `for`.

if use map, you can change async setting `true`

When dealing with asynchronous processing, it is better to use map rather than the for statement.